# No homeomorphism of the interval $[0,1]$ is topologically mixing

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics

I am trying to show that there is no homeomorphism $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ which is topologically mixing (a dynamical system $T:X\to X$ is called topologically mixing, provided, for every pair of open sets $U \subset X$ and $V\subset X$, there exists a natural number $m$ such that for every $n\ge m$ the intersection $T^n(U) \cap V$ is non-empty). Being topologically mixing is an invariant property: if two dynamical systems $T:X\to X$ and $F:Y\to Y$ are conjugate (i.e. one can find a homeomorphism $H:X\to Y$ for which $H \circ T=F\circ H$), then being mixing for one of $T$ or $F$ implies being mixing for the other. Even more, if the mapping $H$ is just a semi-conjugacy (i.e the mapping $H$ is just continuous and surjective), then if $T$ is mixing, so is $F$.

For my first try, my idea was to find a homeomorphism $g: S^1 \to S^1$ which  is a factor of $f$ (i.e. there is a semiconjugacy $h: [0,1] \to S^1$ such that $h\circ f = g\circ h$) and then conclude that being mixing for $f$ implies being mixing for $g$ [which is impossible](https://mathoverflow.net/a/252965/83050). I tried to set $h(t) = \exp (2 \pi \mathbb{i} t) $ and then I defined $g= h^{-1} \circ f \circ h$. But since $h$ is not injective ($h(0) = h(1)$), the mapping $h^{-1}$ is defined on the interval $[0,1)$ and not on all of $[0,1]$. But if for every $(x,y)\in \mathbb R$ with $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ we set $$g(x,y) =\bigg(\cos \Big(2\pi f\big(\frac {1}{2\pi}\cos ^{-1}(x) \big) \Big), \sin \Big(2\pi f\big(\frac {1}{2\pi}\sin ^{-1}(y) \big) \Big) \bigg) $$
Then $h \circ f = g \circ h$. But I have a doubt as to whether $g$ is a homeomorphsm of $S^1$. (I think it is not injective.)

Then, I tried to show that for every homeomorphism $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$, the mapping $f$ is strictly monotone and we must have either $f(0)=0 $ and $f(1)= 1$ or $f(0)= 1$ and $f(1) = 0$. Without loss of generality, (as professor Jason DeVito mentioned in comments)  we can assume $f(0)=0 $ and $f(1)= 1$, otherwise, we work with $f^2$. Now if the only fixed points of $f$ are $0$ and $1$, depending on  $f(t) < t$ or $f(t) >t$, then for any $t \in (0,1)$ we get $f^n(t) \to  0$ or $1$. Hence in each case, we can find two open sets $U$ and $V \subset [0,1]$ such that for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$  and for every $m \ge n$, the intersection $f^m (U) \cap V= \emptyset$. For example, it is enough to take two open intervals $U=(\frac{3}{10}, \frac{4}{10})$ and $V=(\frac{6}{10}, \frac{7}{10})$. Then $f^m(U) \to 0 $ or $1$ as $m\to \infty$ and so $f^m (U) \cap V= \emptyset$ for large $m$.

But what can we do when $f$ has more than $2$ fixed points. Can someone help me?

Comment: (1) how do you conclude that $f^n(t)\to 0$ or $1$ given that $f(t)<t$ or $f(t)>t$? (2) Even if, how does this imply that $f^m(U)\cap V=\emptyset$ eventually? Note that the rate at which $f^n(t)\to 1$ can be different for different $t$.

Comment: I don't think $f^\ast$ fixes $1$ if $f$ doesn't:  $f^\ast(1) = h^{-1}(f(h(1)) h^{-1}(f(0)) = h^{-1}(1) = 0$, which uses the fact that $h^{-1} = h$.  More generally, conjugate homeomorphisms of $[0,1]$ have the same "orientation" (either they're both increasing or both decreasing.)  Nonetheeless, I think you can reduce to the case where $f$ fixes $0$ and $1$ by noting that if $f$ is topologically mixing, then so is $f^n$ for any $n\geq 1$.  Then, if $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = 0$ and $f$ is topologically mixing, then so is $f^2$.

Comment: @freakish Thank you for your comment. (1) Since $f(t) < t$ or $f(t) > t$, then the orbit of every point $t\in (0,1)$, $t, f(t), f^2(t),... $ is a monoton sequence which is bounded. Since $f$ has no fixed point other than $0$ and $1$, this bounded monoton sequence should convergence to $0$ or $1$. (2) Continuouty of $f$ implies the continuouty of $f^n$ for every $n$ and by the part (1), the point of $f^n(U)\to \{0\}$  or $\{1\}$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thank you for your comment. I will edit the question.

Comment: @freakish  I  have edited my question and i have add an explanation about $g: S^1 \to S^1$.

Comment: Am I missing something? We may assume $f$ is increasing, $f(0) =0$, $f(1)=1$. If there is another fixed point $0<x<1$, then if $y < x$, $f(y) < f(x) =x$, so in particular $f^n ([0,x)) \subseteq [0,x)$ does not intersect $(x,1]$

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez No you are not missing something and you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, we may assume $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$ and therefore, that $f$ is increasing.  Now, let's show that $f$ has no other fixed points.

So, assume for a contradiction that $x\notin \{0,1\}$ is a fixed point of $f$.  Because $x\notin\{0,1\}$, the sets $U = [0,x)$ and $V = (x,1]$ are open sets in $[0,1]$.  We claim that these two open sets do not mix.

The key observation is the following:  Let $U'\subseteq U$ be any subset.  Then $f(U')\subseteq U$.  Since $f(U')\subseteq f(U)$, it is sufficient to show that $f(U)\subseteq U$.  First note that $f(U)$ is an interval because $U$ is and $f$ is a homeomorphism.  We also know that $f(0) = 0$ so $0\in f(U)$.  If there is some $u\in U$ with $f(u) > x$, then this implies that there is some $w\in U$ with $f(w) = x$.  Since $f(x) = x$ and $x\notin U$, we have contradicted injectivity of $f$.  Letting $U' = f^n(U)$, we deduce that the iterates $f^n(U)$ are all subsets of $U$.  In particular, since $U\cap V = \emptyset$, it follows that $f^n(U) \cap V = \emptyset$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful answer.

Comment: I  have edited my question and i have add an explanation about $g: S^1 \to S^1$.

Answer (score 0):

I find another solution: if $f:[0,1\to [0,1]$ is mixing, it can not have any fix point execpt $0,1$ (Thanks to Jason DeVito and Aitor Iribar Lopez for their proof for this claim). Now, we have the following Theorem:

> Every two orientation-preserving homeomorphism of $[0,1]$ without fixed points in $(0,1)$ are topologically conjugate.

**Proof**: let $f$ and $g$ are two such homeomorphism with $f(x) > x$ and $g(x)> x$ for any $0 <x < 1$. Let $p\in (0,1)$ be arbitrary and take $h_0 : [p,f(p)]\to [p,g(p)]$ any homeomorphism and let $$h_n = g^n \circ h_0 \circ f^{-n}: [f^n(p),f^{n+1}(p)]\to [g^n(p),g^{n+1}(p)]$$
This homeomorphisms $h_n$ glue together give a homeomorphism $h:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ such that $h\circ f = g\circ h$.

Now define the mapping $f: [0,1]\to [0,1]$ with $f(t)=\sqrt t$. Then $f$ is an orientation-preserving homeomorphism of $[0,1]$ **which is not mixing** and every other orientation-preserving homeomorphism of $[0,1]$ must be topologically conjugate to $f$ and so can not be topologically mixing.